# How to define a weighted graph?

Tags: ocaml

```
A graph in OCaml can be defined in this way

type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a) list;;
let myGraph = Gr[(1,2);(1,3);(1,4);(2,6);(3,5);(4,6);(6,5);(6,7);(5,4)];;
```

But how can I do if I want to attach weights to the edges?

However what is the best way to represent a graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just add it?

```
type weight = float (* or whatever *)
type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a * weight) list
```